# State doesn't update on first action while dispatching 2 sync actions in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to make the [pomodoro clock](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/front-end-libraries-projects/build-a-pomodoro-clock/) as a practice project from FreeCodeCamp. This is a simple clock that switches between your session time and break time whenever the current timer is ended.

I am facing the problem related to redux in react. Here is the state of my app when started.

[image: Initial State]

When I clicks on minus or plus sign then the timer and session/break length in the store will be updated accordingly but this was not happening. The session/break length is updated but the timer reflects the previous value. Here is the screenshot which reflects the problem when I increase the session

[image: Increase Session]

Here is my code which is responsible for this

```
updateSettings(type) {

    if (!this.props.isPlaying) {

        let isInvalid = false; // to show alert if user input is invalid

        if (type === 'increase-session') {
            this.props.increaseSession();
        } else if (type === 'decrease-session') {
            (this.props.session_length > 1) ? this.props.decreaseSession() : isInvalid = true;
        } else if (type === 'increase-break') {
            this.props.increaseBreak();
        } else if (type === 'decrease-break') {
            (this.props.break_length > 1) ? this.props.decreaseBreak() : isInvalid = true;
        }

        if (isInvalid) {
            alert("Times less than 1 minutes is not allowed.");
        } else {
            this.props.setTimer({
                minutes: this.props.session_length,
                seconds: 0,
                percentage: this.getTimeElapsedPercentage(this.props.session_length, 0)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code all the actions are synchronous and when I call `this.props.increaseSession()` then it dispatches the action that increase the session. Then I call `this.props.timer(timerObj)` while this timer object receive the session_length value but this session_length value is not updated means increased (if I increase the session).

My questions is that all the actions are synchronous then why I am receiving the old value while dispatching the `setTimer()`. Any suggestion to solve this will be really appreciated.

As suggested by Roy, If I update the values myself before passing to setTimer then the percentage is not calculated correctly. Here is the function that calculates the progress bar (which is circular bar around timer). This function is responsible for setting the values on start and on each second when the timer starts. Although it can calculate the percentage correctly initially by passing `this.props.session_length` but this will not be the correct session_length. The session length is also using inside `getTimeElapsedPercentage` that is creating the problem. I can tackle this using some logic but I will like to have the correct solution rather than work-around.

```
getTimeElapsedPercentage(minutes, seconds) {
    let totalTimeInSec, timeElapsedInSec, timeRemainingInSec;

    this.props.playType === 'break' ?
        totalTimeInSec = this.props.break_length * 60 :
        totalTimeInSec = this.props.session_length * 60;

    timeRemainingInSec = minutes * 60 + seconds;
    timeElapsedInSec = totalTimeInSec - timeRemainingInSec;

    return timeElapsedInSec / totalTimeInSec * 100;
}
```

## Solution (Workaround - Proper answer is marked below)

As discussed with Roy in the comments I came to know that props only update after each render therefore `this.props.session_length` are giving me the previous values when I am setting the timer using `setTimer(timerObj)`.

So I came into this solution. After first action my store is updated but props are not updated so I import store from my redux code and use `store.getState()` to get the updated values. I used that in my `setTimer(timerObj)` and `getTimeElapsedPercentage` which solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that the props only update after render and `this.props.setTimer` is using the props before render due to which it have old `this.props.session_length` value. This can be fixed by using the react `componentDidUpdate()` life cycle that calls when the props changed and then you can set the timer.

- Remove `setTimer()` from your `updateSettings(type)` function. So the props update only once (i.e. on increaseSession, decreaseSession etc)
- Add the following code in to your component

This is responsible for setting the timer whenever the props changed means now it pass the updated props to the timer.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.session_length !== prevProps.session_length) {
            this.props.setTimer({
                minutes: this.props.session_length,
                seconds: 0,
                percentage: this.getTimeElapsedPercentage(this.props.session_length, 0)
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that's the componentDidUpdate solution. Nice one to see you coded it up in your app. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

I assume `updateSettings(type)` is called each time the button for increasing the session or break is clicked.  In this case when the function is called and arrives at the `this.props.increaseSession()` or `this.props.decreaseSession()` parts, the JavaScript engine calls those functions and it will do its thing. In the meantime the compiler continues with the next lines and arrives at

```
if (isInvalid) {
  alert("Times less than 1 minutes is not allowed.");
} else {
  this.props.setTimer({
    minutes: this.props.session_length,
    seconds: 0,
    percentage: this.getTimeElapsedPercentage(this.props.session_length, 0)
  });
}
```

At this point the increase or decrease session calls have not finished, so the value of `this.props.session_length` is not updated yet. This is the reason why you see that the timer values are always behind the duration values.

My suggestion woud be to move the code that sets the `session_length`, out of this function to a function that is run when the user clicks start. This way you don't have to worry about keeping the two variables in sync. First you let the user set the session and break length. Then, when they click start you then take care of assigning those values to timer.

In case you don't want to go this way I suggest to move setTimer up into the if, else statements and based on the choice use `minutes: this.props.session_length + 1` or `minutes: this.props.session_length - 1` when you call the below.

```
this.props.setTimer({
  minutes: this.props.session_length,
  seconds: 0,
  percentage: this.getTimeElapsedPercentage(this.props.session_length, 0)
});
```

**UPDATE:**

To work around the percentage issue you can update the `getTimeElapsedPercentage` to take an extra argument called `plusMinus`. This then is +1 or -1 depending on the increment or decrement. With a minor change the function it can look like this.

```
getTimeElapsedPercentage(minutes, seconds, plusMinus) {
    let totalTimeInSec, timeElapsedInSec, timeRemainingInSec;

    this.props.playType === 'break' ?
        totalTimeInSec = (this.props.break_length + plusMinus) * 60 :
        totalTimeInSec = (this.props.session_length + plusMinus) * 60;

    timeRemainingInSec = minutes * 60 + seconds;
    timeElapsedInSec = totalTimeInSec - timeRemainingInSec;

    return timeElapsedInSec / totalTimeInSec * 100;
}
```

In updateSettings set it in you if statements

```
let plusMinus = 0; 
if (type === 'increase-session') {
  plusMinus = 1;
} else if (type === 'decrease-session') {
  plusMinus = -1;
}
```

And call is as following

```
percentage: this.getTimeElapsedPercentage(this.props.session_length, 0, plusMinus)
```

I hope this helps and good luck with the project.

Comment: You get it correctly and thanks for your suggestion but whenever I change the settings then it should update the timer. It will not be the expected behaviour to change the settings and timer remains the constant.

I knows that why the problem is occurring but isn't they are synchronous events so I should have receive the updated value. I thinks that I resolve this by using some middleware technique but first I like to know why this is happening or is there any good solution other than middleware.

Comment: No worries and at this stage you don't need middleware. That would make your project more complex then needed. I've updated my answer with an alternative solution

Comment: I have tried this solution before but then it creates the problem on percentage function. Detailed described on my answer with proper description.

Comment: Yes, as you try to keep 2 things in sync you'll need to cover any cases that result from that. That's why I suggested the first solution. Have a look at the update. It covers the percentage function as well with a minor update. See if this works :)

Comment: That's the work-around I am trying to avoid because it disturbs the generic logic. I will like to keep them in sync and if that doesn't happen then I will apply your solution and accept your answer. BTW Thanks for your precious time and back to back helping answers.

Comment: Yes, you will have to accommodate for these cases if you continue with this line of thought. `props` only update after a re-render of the component. Another solution could be to use 'componentDidUpdate()' and call 'getTimeElapsedPercentage()' there. Then you have the updated props. I didn't add this to my answer as this will require react to re-render twice. No problem for a small app but in bigger apps it can become a performance issue. Read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: That's the answer what I am looking for that props only updates after component rendering. Although I didn't use componentDidUpdate because it will mess up with my timerUpdates after each second.

I import store from redux and use `store.getState().duration.session_length` in the percentage function and timer action and that's gives me the updated values. By the way is this approach is good ? and as I import the store myself is there any way to use the store that is provided by `<Provider>` to container components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177897/discussion-between-roy-scheffers-and-mehmood).

Comment: Hi Roy, I have found the proper solution of this problem and if you are interested then you can read my answer on the post.